# Filter inner bag by other field (not constant)

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to run the following scenario but fail.

I start with a list of movies, and group it by {year, rating}.

```
movies = LOAD '/movies_data.csv'
USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:int, name:chararray, year:int, rating:double, duration:int);

grouped = GROUP movies BY (year, rating);
```

The resulting schema is:

```
DESCRIBE grouped;
grouped: {group: (year: int,rating: double),movies: {(id: int,name: chararray,
year: int,rating: double,duration: int)}}
```

Now, for each group I would like to get a list of movie names that contain the year (which is the part of the group name).
So I try the following:

```
model = 
    FOREACH grouped {
    listNames = DISTINCT movies.name;
    listNamesFiltered = FILTER listNames BY name MATCHES group::year;
    GENERATE 
        group.year AS year
        ,group.rating AS rating
        ,listNamesFiltered AS listNamesFiltered     
        ,COUNT(listNamesFiltered) AS countNamesFiltered
        ;};
```

but fail with the message:

```
Invalid field projection. Projected field [group::year] does not exist in schema: name:chararray.
```

Using a constant (like in the following line) works:

```
listNamesFiltered = FILTER listNames BY name MATCHES '.*2010.*';
```

results in:

```
(2010,2.6,{(2010: Moby Dick)},1)
(2010,3.8,{(Saturday Night Live: The 2010s)},1)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it would be a lot easier if you did all the filtering and then did all `GROUP/DISTINCT/COUNT`operations.

**Data**:

```
1       2010: Moby Dick                 2010    2.6     128
2       Saturday Night Live: The 2010s  2010    3.8     127
3       2001: A Space Odyssey           2001    4.0     145
4       Forrest Gump                    1994    4.9     334
```

**Query**:

```
movies =  LOAD 'movie_data.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:int, 
                name:chararray, year:int, rating:double, duration:int);
filtered = FILTER movies BY name MATCHES StringConcat('.*', (chararray)year, '.*');
dump filtered;
```

**Output**:

```
(1,2010: Moby Dick,2010,2.6,128)
(2,Saturday Night Live: The 2010s,2010,3.8,127)
(3,2001: A Space Odyssey,2001,4.0,145)
```

Then do whatever else you were going to do (`COUNT` etc ...).

Comment: That's just a sample data for the real (more complex) task. Let's say that I get the grouped data (and can't do the filtering at a previous stage). So I see the following schema:
grouped: {group: (year: int,rating: double),movies: {(id: int,name: chararray, year: int,rating: double,duration: int)}}, but for some reason can't use group.year for filtering movies.name in any way I try (group::year doesn't help).

Comment: Why would you think you could use `group.year` in that relation?  The relation `listNames` has only one column, `movies.name`.  So when you try to create `listNamesFiltered` by filtering `listNames`, Pig has no idea what you are talking about when you reference `group.year`, because it is not in the relation.

Comment: `listNames` is a bag inside a relation `model`, which also has a field `group.year`. So I am trying to include this field in scope while filtering the bag. Is there such a way?